# pyspark dataframe comparison to find columns difference based on key fields

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, comparison, apache-spark-sql

I have to compare two dataframes to find out the columns differences based on one or more key fields using pyspark in a most performance efficient approach since I have to deal with huge dataframes

I have already built a solution for comparing two dataframes using hash match without key field matching like `data_compare.df_subtract(self.df_db1_hash,self.df_db2_hash)`
but scenario is different if I want to use key field match

***Note: I have provided sample expected dataframe. Actual requirement is any differences from DataFrame 2 in any columns should be retrieved in output/expected dataframe.***

```
DataFrame 1:

+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+--------+
|emp_id| emp_city|emp_name| emp_phone|emp_sal|emp_site|
+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+--------+
|     3|  Chennai|  rahman|9848022330|  45000|SanRamon|
|     1|Hyderabad|     ram|9848022338|  50000|      SF|
|     2|Hyderabad|   robin|9848022339|  40000|      LA|
|     4|  sanjose|   romin|9848022331|  45123|SanRamon|
+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+--------+

DataFrame 2:

+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+--------+
|emp_id| emp_city|emp_name| emp_phone|emp_sal|emp_site|
+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+--------+
|     3|  Chennai|  rahman|9848022330|  45000|SanRamon|
|     1|Hyderabad|     ram|9848022338|  50000|      SF|
|     2|Hyderabad|   robin|9848022339|  40000|      LA|
|     4| sandiego|  romino|9848022331|  45123|SanRamon|
+------+---------+--------+----------+-------+--------+

Expected dataframe after comparing dataframe 1 and 2


+------+---------+--------+----------+
|emp_id| emp_city|emp_name| emp_phone|
+------+---------+--------+----------+
|     4| sandiego|  romino|9848022331|
+------+---------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: if `emp_id` with 1's `emp_city` column is not matching in addition the non matching in the  question. what would be the output dataframe?

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this scenario, I have edited my post to provide more clarity. Answering to your question, even emp_city is required in output dataframe.

Comment: You didn't understand my question, did you? I am asking is what if emp_city of both dataframe for emp_id 1 is different too? how the expected dataframe would look like? what would be emp_city be for `|     4| ???? | romino||9555552331|` ??

Comment: I have updated my original post again(Expected dataframe). I like to get differences from Dataframe 2 in output data frames after comparison between dataframe 1 &2 based on one or more key fields. I hope answered your question now. Thank you

Comment: Please let me know if you have any approach to proceed with this scenario.

Comment: Jack I have answered below :) please check

Answer (score 1):

`subract` function is what you are looking for, which will check all the columns value for each row and gives you a dataframe which are different from the other dataframe.

```
df2.subtract(df1).select("emp_id","emp_city","emp_name","emp_phone")
```

As the api document says

> > Return a new :class:`DataFrame` containing rows in this frame but not in another frame.
> >             This is equivalent to `EXCEPT` in SQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In my real scenario, it is a dynamic data processing.i.e. I have to do similar check for list of tables where I never know the column names which are having different values.

Comment: If you don't know the names you can just leave the select part. It will give you all the columns of dataframe 2. I included select to match with the output your required in the question. so, did the answer helped you? if yes consider accepting and upvoting please :)

Comment: I have to report only columns which are different values but it current solution which will retrieve all columns

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Is there a way to apply the subtract selectively?  For example only consider differences between certain columns?

Comment: With subtract no you can't do that. But you can union them and then use dropDuplicates where you can give column names. its just an idea haven't tested it though @timbram

Comment: @RameshMaharjan very interesting. I’m going to have to try that out.